# How to see create a page of the details of a single product from an Ecommerce

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, material-ui

I am developing an Ecommerce project, I managed to create a product grid and link to an route to the specific product, but i am unable to see the data of the item.
My products code is here

```
const Container = styled.div`
padding: 20px;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
`

const Products = () =>{
    return (
        <Container>
            {products.map(item=>(
                <Product item={item} key={item.id}/>
            ))}
        </Container>
    )
}

export default Products;
```

My product code is here

```
const Product = ({item}:any) => {
    

    return (
        <Container >
            
            <Link to={"/productDetail/" + item.id}>
            <img src={item.image} className='imag'/>
            </Link>

            <Box justifyContent='center' display='flex'>
            <Typography>
                {item.name}
                
            </Typography>
            </Box>
            <Box justifyContent='center' display='flex'>
            <Typography>
                {item.price}

            </Typography>
            </Box>
            <Box justifyContent='center' className='display' >
            <Button className='btn'>Buy</Button>
                </Box>

        </Container>
    )
}

export default Product;
```

And here is my attempt to create a single product page

```
function ProductDetail() {
    
    let { id } = useParams<{ id: string }>();
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={item.image} className='imag' />
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProductDetail;
```

And my route on the home page is like this:

```
<Route exact path="/productDetail/:id" >
          < ProductDetail />
        </Route>
```

Comment: Why are you not geting any error in the `ProductDetail()` ? You have not initialized the `item`.  I don't think so it is complete code.

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing data because item is undefined. If you want to pass data to ProductDetail using navigation then try add state to the `Link` and use inside the `<ProductDetail />`

```
// product-grid page
<Link to="path_to_product_detail" state={item}>...</Link>
```

Now inside `<ProductDetail />` import useLocation method from react router dom which will contain data that is added to the state prop of link component.

```
//product-detail page
    const location = useLocation() // import from react-router-dom
    const item = location.state
```

However, This is not the good practice for your use case, because in the product grid page you will fetch only few details like title, thumbnail & id. But in the product description you have to fetch everything about the product which you may not called while in product grid page. The best way is to populate the detailed data, `item` in our case with api.

Comment: How do I add the state on the state on the product code? and about the rest, I started to code in react recently  so I dont know many things, but in the future I will try to do it with API, thanks

Comment: `const [item, setItem] = useState({})` I used here state hook which manages the state of component. Onchange of state that is when value of item is changed component will automatically rerender. You can change state item using, setItem( ...new data ...) when you fetch data. It would be more clear when you read the docs related to hooks. Documentation is very good.